Staying in galut to avoid Gog Umagog
The Navi describes that the war of Gog Umagog will be devastating. People will be killed, exiled, raped, and so on, all happening in Israel.
My question is, is it wrong to have the following thought- let me stay living in Galut so that I avoid all the pains of the war, and then after the war is over I’ll move to Israel.
Do any commentaries address something like this, like why one would wanna be in Israel if all of this is gonna happen?


Well, based on the premise that Gog UMagog will take place after Moshiach comes (Malbim on Yechezkel 32:17, Satmar Rav in Vayoel Moshe, Maamar 1, Siman 24) it is not a right thing to say "let's stay in galus" after G-d has taken us out of it. Why wait for the end of Golus, and then say "no thanks, there might be a war". That does not sound logical?! –


The commencement of the war of Gog u’Magog, a cycle which spans three actual time periods, already occurred. Yes, it was terrible. We call it “The Shoah”, the Holocaust. Both Gog and Moshiach were present in the world, souls dressed in physical bodies, during that time. The primary sign associated with that stage was the detonation of nuclear bombs (Hiroshima and Nagasaki). That is the prophecy of the clouds in the shape of date palms (mushroom clouds). Yoel 3:3 mentioned by Ramchal.

@Shmuel fair, so I guess the question only arises per those opinions who hold Mashiach will come after the war, or at the very least on the same day. Another question to pile on per your cited view is why would Mashiach gather us all to Israel if there’s gonna be a massive war that’ll devastate us

G-d promises us that if we keep faithful, we will be saved. That is why Gog UMagog will be on Sukkos/Shemini atzeres. The sukkah refers to a metaphorical roof of protection that G-d gives us

Maybe Rabbi Avraham Azulai's recorded statement from the Arizal will be useful to you:

וכשישראל בני קיבוץ גליות יראו שאחיהם נעשה
בריה חדשה, ופורחים באויר ללכת ולדור בגן עדן תחתון ללמוד תורה מפי השם
יתברך, אזי, יתקבלו בני קיבוץ גליות דאגה בלבם ודאבון נפש, ויתרעמו למלך
המשיח ויאמרו וכי אין אנו בני ישראל כמותם, מאין זכו הם להיות רוחניים
בגוף ונפש מה שאין כן אנו ולמה נגרע
When the exiled Jews [who have been brought back to Israel]
witness their brethren being transformed into new spiritual beings and
flying through the air to live in the Lower Gan Eden, where they
will study Torah directly from Hashem, a feeling of anxiety and
sorrow will arise in their hearts. They will complain to the Moshiach, saying, "Are we not also Jews like them? Why have they merited to be spiritual in both body and soul, while we remain
unchanged? Why are we left behind?" [Chesed LeAvraham 3:22]


Do you mind explaining, I don’t really khop the point

I don't know what this means, whether this is literal or not etc, but one thing is clear that those who are in EY when the Moshiach come have an advantage

Also note that the Chesed LeAvraham also says that Moshiach will find 7.000 yidden in Eretz Yisroel when he comes. Through Satmar-sources, this is explained as 7.000 yidden that are fully connected with Hashem by observing torah en mitzvos to the full extend.

Ignore, @Shmuel. Fascinating source BTW. Reassuring to know that I will be among many millions of other people who didn't make the cut. We are all zoche to yemot ha moshiach, techiyat hametim and Olam haba

@RabbiKaii Amen! Thanks for bringing the original source from the Chesed L'Avraham! Great source!

@RabbiKaii already did bring the famous explanation from the Chesed L'Avraham. However, if you read a little bit further (down), you will read that Rabbi Avraham Azulai explains that Moshiach will be complementing the people that risked their lives in going to Eretz Yisroel, "in order to merit a pure soul, not caring about their health [...] or to be captured by harsh lords" (Chesed L'Avraham, Even Shetiya, Maayan 3, Nahar 22):

And the Messiah says to them: "It is already known and widely proclaimed that all the attributes of the Holy One, blessed be He, measure for measure. Those who were in the diaspora and made efforts to come to the Land in order to merit a pure soul, not caring about their wealth or their bodies, whether by sea or land, not fearing to drown in the sea or be robbed on land, or to be captured by harsh lords. Because they acted primarily from their spirit and soul, not from their body or wealth, therefore, they returned in spiritual measure for measure. But you, who were capable of coming to the Land like them, were degraded to come for the sake of material wealth, and you were concerned about your wealth and your body. You made the essence secondary, from your soul and your spirit. Therefore, you remain materialistic measure for measure.

So, you ask, would it be better to wait in Golus and to wait until the war of Gog UMagog will be over? Well, according to the Chesed L'Avraham, the people that risk their life, health, wealth and more in order to go to Eretz Yisroel after Moshiach comes, in order to purify themselves, will be greatly awarded by G-d.
Maybe this is also how we can explain the famous statement that Moshiach will find only 7.000 Yidden in Eretz Yisroel. These Yidden are the ones that were willing to risk their lives in order to live in Eretz Yisroel.

Interesting thanks for sharing. It’s interesting though that u mention coming after mashiach arrives, but I wonder what about whether one should come before

That is a different topic :). It is the role of Moshiach to bring in the exiles. We are not meant to hasten the end. The Torah says that G-d put us into exile, and He is the one who gets us out of it. Not we.
